# WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG-LAYOUT-IN-SCREEN how to draw over navigaion bar in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a simple android app to display a black bar across the top and bottom of the screen to hide the novel rounded screen corners that every manufacturer insists on putting on every phone. This will require drawing over both the status bar and navigation bar, as a system wide overlay that shows over all other apps.

I can use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG-LAYOUT-IN-SCREEN to draw over the status bar, but this does not allow for drawing over the navigation bar.

What is the parameter I need to use so I can draw over the navigation bar as well?

All the other solutions I have found only apply to the app itself, and not to the overlay elements.

I also need to add something to stop the overlay from rotating when an app goes to landscape mode, I still want to be able to use apps in landscape, but the overlay should stay in portrait.
I have already added android:screenOrientation="portrait" to the activity tag in my manifest file but this does not make a difference as it does not affect the overlay itself.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "draw over navigation bar"? You can try and hide the bar as the app enters full screen or you can draw under the navigation bar. Draw under means your navigation bar is transparent and the data can be seen but click events are primarily on the navigation bar. Hiding the navigation bar as soon as your app starts, line in games is something you can do if you want that and whenever the user slides from the bottom it should show him the navigation bar.

Comment: I dont want to hide the navigation bar, as I am not making a fullscreen app, I am making an overlay that appears over all other apps, and  I still want to be able to use the navigation bar. I want my overlay to appear on top of the navigation bar, it is only a thin black bar to hide the rounded corners of the bottom edge of the screen so will not block out the back, home and recents icons, but will hide a section of the navigation bar at the bottom

Comment: I am not following really, can you give me an example as code or picture of what you want to achieve. You can change the color of the navigation bar, you can hide it, you can draw behind it but you can't draw over the navigation bar. Just give me something and I'll try to help you.

Comment: Sorry that was a little hard to understand. On the left in this image is what I have now, and on the right is what I want

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv6wO.png

Comment: I know it is possible to draw over the navigation bar, as this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=immersive.duna.com.immersivemode

Comment: hides the navigation bar by redrawing the current app over the top

Comment: because overscan would normally be used for this, but has been removed in android 11

Comment: You can get the source code of that app from .apk probably. Google to find how to do that but I think it just hides the status bar, navigation bar, and when it hides both it just goes in full-screen mode. If you want your layout to be visible behind the navigation bar just set NO_LIMITS on your activity and set the navigation bar color to transparent. I don't know how to "draw over navigation bar" if that's even possible which I think it is not.